# IF statement with concatenate and round in Excel

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, concatenation, rounding

I am trying to create an IF statement formula in excel that converts minutes to days and hours depending on the amount. Then rounds the value to 1 or 2 decimal points and adds the descriptive text (days, hours, etc) to the end

I have tried the following which converts and adds text but does not round:

```
=IF(L15>=1440, CONVERT(L15,"min","day") & CONCATENATE(L15," days"), 
 IF(L15>=60, CONVERT(L15,"min","hr") & CONCATENATE(L15," hours"), 
 IF(L15<=59, CONVERT(L15,"min","min") & CONCATENATE(L15," mins"))))
```

Comment: perhaps put the round() function around L15 ie CONVERT(round(L15,2),"min","day"), but without any example cannot test.

Comment: `& CONCATENATE` seems a little excessive since & is the short form of CONCATENATE

Comment: It seems like your current formula will produce the converted number in L15 followed by the number of minutes (contents of L15) followed by the units of the convert value.  Also since L15 is supposed to be in minutes, there is no need to convert minutes to minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I would adjust your formula as follows and based on you wanting to round the final number

```
=IF(L15>=1440,ROUND(L15/1440,2)&" days",IF(L15>=60,ROUND(L15/60,2)&" hours",ROUND(L15,2)&" minutes"))
```

the `,2` in the ROUND function tell excel how many decimal places to calculate to.  if format is set to general, trailing 0s will not be displayed.  If you only want 1 decimal calculation then change the `,2` to `,1`.